# Ruby コードチャレンジ

Tags: ruby

一つの文字列を因数として取り、文字列が大文字だった場合は、そのindex番号を配列に返すというメソッドを作成してくださいという、コードチャレンジです。
このケースで存在しない配列の6番目を返したり、期待通りのメソッドになりません。

```
def capital_index("rABbiT")
#your code
end
```

```
capital_index("rABbiT") -> [1, 2, 5]
```

**My code**

```
def capital_index(string)
  arr = []
  i = 0
    while i <= string.length
      if string[i] == string.upcase[i]
        arr.push(i)
        p arr
      end
      i += 1
    end

end
capital_index("rABbiT")
```

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: `find_all()` を使う方法もあります。`def capital_index(string) (0 ... string.length).find_all {|i| string[i].match /[[:upper:]]/} end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一番まずいのはここですね。

```
while i <= string.length
```

Rubyの文字列のインデックスは0から始まるんで、6文字の文字列なら最大で5まで、つまり

```
while i < string.length
```

としないといけません。

また、メソッドからの戻り値として配列を戻さないといけないようなので、それも追加しないといけないですね。

と言うわけで全体はこんな感じ。

```
def capital_index(string)
  arr = []
  i = 0
  while i < string.length #(1)
    if string[i] == string.upcase[i]
      arr.push(i)
      #p arr
    end
    i += 1
  end
  arr #(2)
end
```

これで「存在しない配列の6番目を返し」は、なくなるはずです。そのあとの「たり」が何なのかがちょっと気になるんですが。

---

あるいは、`while`の代わりに`for`を使うこともできるでしょう。

```
def capital_index(string)
  arr = []
  for i in 0...string.length
    if string[i] == string[i].upcase
      arr.push(i)
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

---

こんな書き方もできます。

```
def capital_index(string)
  string.chars.map.with_index {|ch,ix| [ch,ix]}
    .select{|pair| pair[0] == pair[0].upcase}
    .map{|pair| pair[1]}
end
```

他にももっとうまいやり方があるかもしれません。とりあえず最初の修正だけで目的の動作をするはずだと思うんですが、何かありましたらお知らせください。

Answer (score 3):

こういうのはどうでしょうか？

```rb
def capital_index(str)
  (0...str.length).select {|i| str[i] == str[i].upcase }
end

capital_index('rABbiT') #=> [1, 2, 5]
```